# How many elements are in the Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$ Let A = (x∈Z | -3 < 6x < 41 ) $$

And $$ Let B = (x∈Z | -2 < 5x < 13 ) $$

How many elements are in the Cartesian product A x B?

Comment: How many elements are there in $A$? In $B$?

Comment: I'm not too sure.

Comment: You can try to figure out what is the minimum and maximum number in $A$ for starters.

Answer (score 1):

**$\color{red}{\text{You have to choose numbers which are in }\mathbb{Z}\cap (\frac{-3}{6} < x <\frac{41}{6})}$**
$A = (x∈Z | -3 < 6x < 41 )=(x∈Z | \frac{-3}{6} < x <\frac{41}{6}\sim6/.. )=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}\Rightarrow cardinal A=7 $

and similarly $$ B = (x∈Z | -2 < 5x < 13 )= (x∈Z | \frac{-2}{5} < x <\frac{13}{5}\sim 2/.. )=\{0,1,2\}\Rightarrow cardinal B=3 $$
hence $cardinalA\times B= cardinal A\times cardinal B =3\times 7=21$